# Cannot start HAProxy

Tags: proxy, haproxy, start

When im starting HAProxy it says:

```
Starting haproxy: [ALERT] 038/154339 (770) : Starting proxy proxy1: cannot bind socket                                                            [FAILED]
```

My config:

```
global
daemon
log /dev/log local4
maxconn 400000
ulimit-n 810000

defaults
log global
contimeout 4000
clitimeout 42000
srvtimeout 43000

listen proxy1 31.***.50.247:8217
mode tcp
balance leastconn
server proxy1_1  198.**.**0.70:25565
```

A bit of my IPs are hidden from serverfault.

Comment: Is that actually your IP address?

Comment: No, a bit of the ip adress is hidden.

Comment: How was this resolved ?

Comment: The host was not able to run HAProxy.

Comment: @xCoderTV: What does that mean ?

Comment: Please stop adding "SOLVED" to your question. The correct way to mark the question as solved is to click the check mark next to the answer that solved the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is RHEL or some derivative, if you have SELinux on it probably wouldn't appreciate you running haproxy on a port the policy is not familiar with.

Try restarting the process, let it fail. Then run `ausearch -ts recent -m avc`. If its coming back with results (text), then try doing these two commands.

```
semanage port -a -p tcp -t commplex_port_t 8217
semanage port -a -p tcp -t commplex_port_t 25565
```

This will ammend the SELinux policy to be aware that haproxy is is listening on these ports.

The strange label "commplex_port_t" is the type definition of port 5000 which (I assume) haproxy defaults to if you dont choose a port. In `/etc/services` port 5000 claims is registered to the `commplex-main` service, hence the name of the label being out of place.

Answer (score 1):

```
cannot bind socket [FAILED]
```

That typically means one of two things:

1. There is already another daemon listening on that port.
2. You're using a port below 1024 and you're running haproxy as a non-privileged user.

Since it looks like you're using port 8217 and 25565, #2 isn't the case.

To determine if there is already something listening on that port:

```
$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep 8217
```

Comment: No one is running on that port. My vps.me forward is   proxy1  31.220.50.***  8217  25565  TCP